# What is the DDL to rename column in MSAccess?

Tags: ms-access, ddl

What is the DDL to rename a column in MS Access? Something along the lines of:

`alter table myTable rename col1 to col2`

which does not work for MSAccess 2000 format databases.  I'm using OLEDB or ADO.NET with a MSAccess 2000 format db but would be grateful of any hint at the syntax or a suggestion as to how to achieve this using ADO.NET in some other way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am at home and can't test this at the moment, but I think this should work.  This [site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP010322071033.aspx) has information about it.

```
ALTER TABLE thetable ALTER COLUMN fieldname fieldtype
```

**Edit**  I tested this a bit and oddly enough, you can't rename a column that I can find.  The `ALTER COLUMN` syntax only allows for changing type. Using SQL, it seems to be necessary to drop the column and then add it back in. I suppose the data could be saved in a temporary table.

```
alter table test drop column i;
alter table test add column j integer;
```

Answer (score 8):

I do not believe you can do this, other than by appending a new column, updating from the existing column and then deleting the 'old' column.

It is, however, quite simple in VBA:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set fld = db.TableDefs("Table1").Fields("Field1")
fld.Name = "NewName"
```

Comment: ...using DAO, of course. DAO is the natural interface for controlling Jet, and while DDL can be convenient, it's never been well-supported by Jet/ACE. I've never cared, since I don't alter my schema via code (I do it by hand, since it's something that happens once in a blue moon -- it would take longer to script it and test it than it would take to just do it).

Comment: I found that I had to set the db variable to DBEngine(0)(0) to keep the object open otherwise I was getting an error "Object invalid or no longer set"

Answer (score 5):

My solution, simple but effective:

```
Dim tbl as tabledef
set tbl = currentdb.TableDefs("myTable")
tbl.fields("OldName").name = "Newname"
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer provided by Fionnuala using DDL is

```
ALTER TABLE [your table] ADD COLUMN [your newcolumn] Text(250)
UPDATE [your table] SET [your table].[newcolumn] = [your table].[old column]
ALTER TABLE [your table] DROP COLUMN [oldcolumn]
```

Note that obviously you can specify any column type for your new column, and Text(250) is just for illustration

Answer (score 3):

In VBA you can do this to rename a column:

```
Dim acat As New ADOX.Catalog
Dim atab As ADOX.Table
Dim acol As ADOX.Column
Set acat = New ADOX.Catalog
acat.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
Set atab = acat.Tables("yourTable")
For Each acol In atab.Columns
    If StrComp(acol.Name, "oldName", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        acol.Name = "newName"
        Exit For
    End If
Next acol
```

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into this before and there is no DDL statement that can do this for you. Only method is to add a new column, copy the data and remove the old column.