# How to set field properties for Column in MDB using Java

Tags: java, ms-access, input-mask

I am creating a migration script for the MDB database. In this migration i need to add some Tables in the MDB. This script is written in Java and i am able to create Table with Column Names and their field types but i am not able to put other properties like Input Mask and length etc.

Lets say i need to put input mask called "Password" on column of type Text. How this can be done through Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Many of the expended properties of Access database fields are only accessible via DAO (as far as I know), so you will probably need to use the same technique I described in my answer to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17713207/2144390).

In this case you would use...

```
fld.Properties("InputMask") = "Password"
```

...in the VBScript code.

Comment: Thomoson. Thanks. i am trying to do the same.