# How to rename a column in sql with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

How can i Rename a Column using Pyodbc ?

I have tried

```
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN column_name to new_column_name")
```

With the result

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in ALTER TABLE statement. (-3554) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's help about Microsoft Access [ALTER TABLE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177883(v=office.12).aspx). I don't think it's possible to rename column with this statement.
So it looks like best you can do it's just drop and recreate column:

```
alter table table_name add column new_column_name column_type;
alter table table_name drop column column_name;
```

You can also copy data from old column to new one between these statements.

**update** here's similar question [What is the DDL to rename column in MSAccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049245/what-is-the-ddl-to-rename-column-in-msaccess)

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot Change Column Name If Their Is Date In The Table.
First Drop That Table

Code :

```
 alter table table_name
 drop(column_name);
```